# Django DeletionMixin and BaseDetailView causes a strange error with Mypy 0.991

Tags: django, mypy

So I have a very simple Django view that basically deletes a user account:

```py
class UserDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    success_message = _("Your account has been deleted")
    success_url = reverse_lazy('account_logout')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

After upgrading to Mypy 0.991 I am seeing this error:

```
error: Definition of "object" in base class "DeletionMixin" is incompatible with definition in base class "BaseDetailView"  [misc]
```

For the life of me I can't figure out what this means, any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: This is extremely weird, because they [are](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/blob/master/django-stubs/views/generic/detail.pyi#L23) [compatible](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/blob/master/django-stubs/views/generic/edit.pyi#L64) (both `DeletionMixin` and `BaseDetailView` have `object: M` annotation, where M is the same typevar - both classes are generic in M), and `object` is even redeclared explicitly in [`DeleteView`](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/blob/master/django-stubs/views/generic/edit.pyi#L70).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by bug https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/issues/1227, which in turn seems to be caused by bug https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9031. In other words, the error is not in your code. Until the underlying bugs are fixed, you can work around this using `# type: ignore`.